# I can't lock my screen after upgrading to 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen, lts

I've recently upgraded my desktop PC from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

After the update, I can't seem to lock my screen. I click the lock option by using the panel on top-right, but nothing happens.

What could be the cause of this, and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you try: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'false'`?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli now I did, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: See my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244695/ubuntu-20-04-not-work-lock-screen-after-update/1281977#1281977